# How to change default port for brew installed jenkins in macos?

Tags: macos, jenkins

In macbook pro jenkins-lts 2.492.2 installed by brew with default port 8080 but port 8080 is default port for other application so that i want to change jenkins default port like 7070 0r 8888.
please help

Answer (score 2):

You can change the port by editing the Jenkins plist file.

The location where it is stored may vary but i found the file here:

/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jenkins-lts/2.289.2/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist

I use a macbook pro m1 (2020)

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Answer (score 1):

```
    **This solution for macos based jenkins installation with brew**
    
    the Jenkins port on macOS,you must pay attention to the way of installation of Jenkins.
    
    I have installed Jenkins LTS by brew command
    
    brew install jenkins-lts
    
    So my Jenkins plist file is here:
    
    /usr/local/Cellar/jenkins-lts/2.492.2/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist
    
    You can modify the httpPort value from default 8080 to the other value,and then save the file.
    as shown below
    
    **vi homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist**
    
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/bin/java</string>
      <string>-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true</string>
      <string>-jar</string>
      <string>/usr/local/opt/jenkins-lts/libexec/jenkins.war</string>
      <string>--httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1</string>
      <string>--httpPort=7070</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
    
    You must try these commands(specific to macos) to restart your Jenkins and make the port modification works.
    
    
        brew services stop jenkins-lts
        brew services start jenkins-lts
        
        prkumar@KLL34873 ~ % brew services stop jenkins-lts
        Stopping `jenkins-lts`... (might take a while)
        ==> Successfully stopped `jenkins-lts` (label: homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts)
        prkumar@KLL34873 ~ % brew services start jenkins-lts
        ==> Successfully started `jenkins-lts` (label: homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts)
    
    Note:If you installed Jenkins LTS,you must pay attention that your command must be jenkins-lts, not jenkins.
```

Comment: Thanks frank edekobi , your solution worked me.